# Address boundary error

Tags: c, memory

UPD2:
The algoritm generates bytes out of allocated range. So it's a logical mistake.

UPD:
modifyed printf to

```
printf("%d\n", bytes);
```

But the result is same - SIGSEGV.

I am new in pure c coding. This is simple near "hello world" app:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


void encode2(int src){
    unsigned char * result =(unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) *10);
    int bytes = 0;
    bool More;
    do{
        uint8_t Byte = src & 0x7f;
        src >> 7;
        More = !((((src == 0) && ((Byte & 0x40) == 0)) ||
                  ((src == -1) && ((Byte & 0x40) != 0))));
        if (More)
            Byte |= 0x80;
        result[bytes] = Byte;
        bytes++;
    } while(More);
    printf(bytes);
    unsigned char * str = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * bytes);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<bytes; i++){
        str[i] = result[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    encode2(10);
    /*printf("%s\n",p);*/
    return 0;
}
```

> Job 1, './leb128' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

Tried to google SIGSEGV but couldn't found whats wrong?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: where is the bound for `result[bytes]`?

Comment: `printf(bytes);`..... you don't do that.

Comment: Sorry, what means "where is the bound?" - I allocated array of 10 chars. That is the bound as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check your do while loop 
because in that `bool More` never going to set false, because of that you are accessing extra memory (`result[bytes] = Byte;`
) so you getting error.

Answer (score 4):

A `SIGSEGV` just tells you, that you have accessed memory, you have not allocated. Your call to `printf()` directly after the while loop causes that `SIGSEGV`.

The first parameter to `printf()` is a `char*`, that points to the format string as a null-terminated character array. Let's say, `bytes` is 2. Then C will interpret 2 as a memory address and in `printf()` try to read the null terminated string that is at address `0x0000000000000002`. That is most probably not accessible for you.

I guess, what you mean there is `printf("%d\n", bytes);`

Please be aware, that you'll have to `free()` all the memory, you have allocated using `malloc()`. There is no garbage collector in C, so all the memory you allocate stays around untill you `free()` it again. You don't want that in longer running processes.

Comment: I modifyed printf. The same result.

Comment: Do you get the output from the `printf()` before the `SIGSEGV`? If not, I'd guess, your calculation of `More` is wrong and you write past `result[9]`.